# How pass "this" in base class' method for a generic method parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I have a static method in my base class:

```
private static <T extends BaseClass<? super T>> T getIt(Class<T> theClass, T obj)
{ ... }
```

I want to have an instance method in the base class that can pass `this` to that method:

```
public <T extends BaseClass<? super T>> T getSelfChanged()
{
    T changedSelf = getIt( getClass(), this );
}
```

But the use of`this` throws the error:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found BaseClass<T> required "? extends BaseClass"
```

Trying to cast it, doesn't work either:

```
//DOESN'T WORK
T changedSelf = getIt( getClass(),  ( T ) this );
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: How are you expecting to pass `this` to the method when `this` is of type `BaseClass` and the method expects `T extends BaseClass` ?

Comment: @arizzle because `this` in a base class can be cast to the child class' type. If I were to return `this` in a method as an object, I could cast it to the child class because that's what the object is.

Comment: Downcasting isn't allowed in Java. You cannot downcast from `BaseClass` to `T extends BaseClass`.

Comment: @arizzle Why doesn't this alternative work? `public <T extends BaseClass<? super T>> T getSelfChanged(T self)`

Comment: you would need to pass the class of `T` as well, this would work for example:

`public <T extends BaseClass<? super T>> T getSelfChanged(Class<T> clazz, T self)
    {
        T changedSelf = getIt(clazz, self);
    }`